# 'In' operator comparison - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below test data:

[image]

I have a variable `@var int = '5'` and I want to see if `@var` exists in one of the `'data'` row in the table, I should report `pid,true`. So is it possible to do

case when `@var` in (data....) ? That is can I find `@var` using `'in'` condition in the table data column?

Any help?!

Comment: Comma delimited data in a single field is a bad idea. Fix your schema and this becomes as simple as `SELECT pid FROM your_fixed_table where data = 5;`

Comment: Agree, poor design, but if you're stuck charindex() would help, you would just need to convert @var.  Something like charindex(convert(varchar,@var),data,1).  A value greater than 0 means it exist.

Comment: Another solution would be to implement a string-splitter table-valued function (there are several here).  Then you could go `Where @var in (select element from string_split(data, ','))`.